# Make javascript function only run one time

Tags: javascript

On a page on my site a pop up displays when the mouse leaves the window. If the pop up is closed it will display again whenever the cursor is moved outside the window. I would like the pop up to display only once.

Here's code I am using...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Exit intent
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}


// Exit intent trigger
addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {

    if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null ) {
        $('.lightbox').slideDown(50);
    };

});



// Closing the Popup Box
$('a.close').click(function(){
   $('.lightbox').slideUp(50);
});
});
</script>
```

I've tried to figure out using the javascript once function and removeEventListener but nothing I am trying is working. For example I try this:

```
function removeHandler() {
    document.getElementById(".lightbox").removeEventListener("mouseout", evt);
}
```

Comment: You've got the right idea with the `removeHandler` but you want to pass the function itself to `removeEventListener`, not `evt`. So if you did `function onMouseOut(evt) { ...` you would do `removeEventListener(onMouseOut)`.

Comment: Since you seem to be using jQuery, use jQuery to bind the handler.

Comment: @Felix Kling the other question/answer is for a click event. It might be a solution for my situation but I don't want to only be able to close the pop up one time. I want the pop up to only display one time.

Comment: You can apply that solution to any event type. The type of the event is rather irrelevant.

Comment: @Felix Kling well I appreciate your responses but like I said I have tried. That's why I posted the question here.

Comment: So you already tried the solution in the duplicate? What didn't work?

Comment: @FelixKling Well, since I'm new to everything (html, javascript, etc.) and am trying to learn, I am probably not doing something correctly. If I could tell you what that was, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, but anyways. The solution to your problem can be found in the duplicate question. Apply it to your situation. If you have problems doing that, let us know.